# How do I get water from a well into my waterskin?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

I figured out that I can <kbd>u</kbd>se the well, then `Lower the bucket`, then <kbd>u</kbd>se the well again, and then `Raise the bucket`. I'm guessing the bucket is full of water, but how do I fill my waterskin with the water in the bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. <kbd>u</kbd>se the well.
2. `Lower the bucket`
3. <kbd>u</kbd>se the well again.
4. `Raise the bucket`
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>nteract with your `waterskin`.
6. `Fill _ waterskin from _ bucket (direction)`